# Count total rows

Tags: php, mysql

I do like to have the user be able to see how many pictures they have uploaded.

This code is in place:

```
$result = mysql_query("select count(1) from userid = '$userid' where FROM picture");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$total = $row[0];
echo "Total picture: " . $total;
```

But it shows nothing. When I remove 'userid', it counts all rows in the picture table.

I tried and failed.

Error:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in on line 14

Comment: Is that SQL you're trying to write? The syntax is totally wrong. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/retrieving-data.html

Comment: Try not using `mysql_` first.

Comment: why my posted? someone edit?

Comment: Yes, I edited your question - question vandalism is _always_ reverted here.

Comment: @halfer what does u mean? vandalism? I see my posted just now with wired words. Thats wht i am asking who edit my post.

Comment: Vandalism = to deliberately wreck something. The edits came from your user account; see the edit history here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15997220/revisions. If this is not you, then I wonder if you have a virus or malicious bot on your computer?

Comment: @halfer I already flag some of them. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL query is not correct, such that `$result` is not a row set.  This is why you're getting the errors on `mysql_fetch_array()`. Hypothetically*, if you had checked `mysql_error()` immediately after executing that query, this would tell you the error that occurred.

Your query is:

```
select count(1) from userid = '$userid' where FROM picture
```

You should have something like:

```
SELECT count(1) AS picture_count FROM picture WHERE userid = '$userid'
```

Then you can get your total at `$row['picture_count']`.

*As others have advised, the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.  Refer [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php).

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended
>   for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead,
>   either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also the
>   MySQL API Overview for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

The [mySql Improved (mysqli_*)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) functions are going to be easiest to implement.

Comment: @user2279205 Thanks for the accept, I appreciate it.  Updated my answer with links to the manual for the mysqli library.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by `mysql_num_rows`:

> [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) — Get number of rows in result

Like:

```
echo mysql_num_rows($result);
```

And the **`mysql_*` [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) is deprecated in PHP 5.5 and later, so either use `PDO` or `mysqli`**.

Comment: I was going to -1 for `mysql_`, but you were smart and added the note.